# How to create a pandas column with a time based constraint on another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like below, there are only 2 `categories A and B`. Each name can be associated with either of them in each row. When the name appears again, I need other 2 columns which indicate the count of `category A` and `category B` for that name in last 5 transactions of that name. If there are less than 5 transactions before that, then the output should be `"-1"`. So, I have clubbed the dataframe on names by sorting on names and then on Date Due, but not sure how to proceed further.

```
Document Number   Date Due  Name    Category
    21175370      9/20/17   Max        A
    20762835      8/20/17   Max        A
    21134931      8/25/17   Emily      B
    20784776      8/19/17   John       A
    20874477      8/4/17    Doe        B
    20874568      8/4/17    Doe        B
    20874575      8/4/17    Doe        B
    19784032      5/9/17    Doe        B
    19980723      5/25/17   Doe        B
    20833755      9/16/17   Doe        A
```

The output would look like this:

```
Document Number   Date Due  Name    Category  Category_A_Count  Category_B_Count
    21175370      9/20/17   Max        A              -1              -1
    20762835      8/20/17   Max        A              -1              -1
    21134931      8/25/17   Emily      B              -1              -1 
    20784776      8/19/17   Doe        A              -1              -1
    20874477      8/4/17    Doe        B              -1              -1
    20874568      8/4/17    Doe        B              -1              -1
    20874575      8/4/17    Doe        B              -1              -1
    19784032      5/9/17    Doe        B              -1              -1
    19980723      5/25/17   Doe        B               1              4
    20833755      9/16/17   Doe        A               0              5
```

I have tried something by changing the pandas dataframe to list, this does the work, but how can i do it in pandas? :

```
vendorList = list(vendorLast5["Name"])
cat = list(vendorLast5["Category"])
print type(vendorList)
catA = [-1, -1, -1, -1]
catB = [-1, -1, -1, -1]
for i in range(0, len(vendorList)):
    if(i > 4):
        countA = 0
        countB = 0
        for j in range(i-5, i):
            if(vendorList[j] != vendorList[i]):
                countA = -1
                countB = -1
                break
            if(cat[j] == "A"):
                countA = countA+1
            else:
                countB=countB+1
        catA.append(countA)
        catB.append(countB)
```

Comment: I dont understand how you have 1,0 and 4 and 5 for last two rows. Could you explain a bit

Comment: @Dark - So, for Doe, in the second last row, out of the last 5 times he was involved, he was in category A once and category B 4 times, by the last row, he was in category A 0 times and category B 5 times for last 5 times from this transaction.

Comment: Have you tried any approach, do add it here. This sounds complicated. Since we see no code it will be much like completing your assignment behalf of you.

Comment: @Dark - haha, no it's not an assignment, I am trying some stuff with a dataframe, and this came up. But, ya i get your point. Actually, I tried something similar to what you had suggested yesterday by pivoting it on A and B. But couldn't proceed. So, trying to change these 2 columns to lists, since it is sorted &, i have 2 for loops to check the values and make 2 lists with required values checking the namesList and then will merge these 2 newly created lists with this dataframe as columns, but I can't figure out how to do it in pandas, i will paste the code I am trying with lists in  a while.